# Horizontally "split" element in pure CSS with different contents in each half

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to find a way to give an element a "split" appearance, allowing one of two contents to be displayed depending on which half the user hovers over.

This is the version I came up with: top text is set to half-height and moved on top of the bottom text. When user hovers over top it rolls out to cover the bottom, and when user hovers over bottom, top rolls up to hide its contents.

```css
.container {
    width: 2em;
    font-size: 5rem;
    text-align: center;
    font: "Consolas";
}

.bottom, .top {
    line-height: 2em;
    background-color: black;
}

.bottom {
    color: yellow;
}

.top {
    color: lime;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    height:1em;
    margin-top: -2em;
    position:relative;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.bottom:hover + .top {
    height: 0.6em;
}

.top:hover {
    height: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="bottom">MAX</div>
    <div class="top">MIN</div>
</div>
```

Feels very... janky. Is there a better option for implementing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using `clip-path` easier to manage

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.container>div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: 0.8s clip-path,z-index 0s 0.8s;
  background-color: black;
}

.container> :first-child {
  color: yellow;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 50% 0);
}

.container> :last-child {
  margin-top: -1.5em; /* equal to line-height */
  color: red;
  clip-path: inset(50% 0 0 0);
}

.container>div:hover {
  clip-path: inset(0 0 0 0);
  transition: 0.8s clip-path,z-index 0s 0s;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="bottom">MAX</div>
  <div class="top">MIN</div>
</div>

<div class="container" style="font-size:40px">
  <div class="bottom">Top</div>
  <div class="top">down</div>
</div>
```